# String in PHP with ">"

Tags: php, html, string

I want to execute a command on my Linux, triggerd by PHP/HTML.
Thats my code:

```
            <td> Status: </td>
            <?php  
                $kommando = "asterisk -rx \'database get SW OFFICE-OPEN\'  \> /etc/asterisk/abstatus.txt";
                shell_exec($kommando);          
            ?>
            <td>
```

The problem is that the `$kommando` String is getting stopped at `\>`, the rest is just drawn on my Site.

First I was using `>` only, then as `\>` - nothing worked.

Can you help me please?

Comment: you have too many \'s

Comment: `htmlentities()` ?

Comment: The syntax for the Command is: asterisk -rx 'database get SW OFFICE-OPEN'  - so I need to have those right? Otherwise it will cut it?

Comment: What a mess! Doing things things without **prior understanding** what it is needed for is pointless. You will make it even worse. Do you know why you need to use `\`? Do you know when? do you know for what characters? If not -> google "escaping" or go to[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) first

Comment: if HTML-strings in PHP had to look like this, I would have never touched PHP.

Comment: Addendum to my first comment. For example: `$ergebnis = "\<p style=\"color:green\"\> Aktiv \</p\>";` that should read as `$ergebnis = "<p style=\"color:green\"> Aktiv </p>";` or `$ergebnis = '<p style="color:green"> Aktiv </p>';`

Comment: Instead of fixing it by yourself, use `escapeshellargs` function

Comment: Marcin Orlowski thanks for beeing NOT helpful at all, since I am a beginner how about beeing helpful instead of a bitchy little kid?

And it doesnt cut in the HTML strings, it cuts in the first one with the linux code

Comment: @VitaminAqua That's how you treat people giving you free help? Feel free to visit http://stackoverflow.com/jobs if you don't like what you get here.

Comment: If the html strings are not relevant, you should remove them; just put the code that causes the problem and perhaps a bit of context.

Comment: He wasnt helping at all.

Comment: Don't forget to tag people you want to be notified of your reply by putting an @ symbol before their name (tab auto-completes it). Like this: @MarcinOrlowski.

Comment: @Mike, thats good to know. Thanks.

I edited it, now it should be clear :)

Comment: @VitaminAqua Can you explain what you mean by *String is getting stopped at `\>`*? How do you determine this? What would be the expected behavior?

Comment: @Mike after the \> the PHP script is printed to the screen

Comment: Get rid of those backslashes. There is nothing special about `<`, `>` or `'` in a double-quoted PHP string. Those need not to be escaped.

Comment: @ROAL I need them in order to work correctly. It is a Linux command, it needs those '

Comment: `after the \> the PHP script is printed to the screen` OK, so I'm flagging as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-i-can-see-it-on-source-code-of-page **edit** Already voted to close for another reason in case someone else wants to flag it as dupe.

Comment: @VitaminAqua Yes, those remain there, but the slashes go away, like so: `$kommando = "asterisk -rx 'database get SW OFFICE-OPEN'  > /etc/asterisk/abstatus.txt";`

Comment: @ROAL okay, thanks. But that, sadly, didnt fix the issue. :(

Comment: @Mike I know, but I got a feeling (still, feel free to correct me with this) that all who posted a comment to this question will be notified anyway. Direct notification with `@` will be needed if someone is not there yet only. But I need to check that - maybe I imagined this :)

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Pretty sure you're imagining things hehe. I even posted a [question on Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/261541/notify-new-users-when-their-comment-will-not-ping-anyone) about this.

Comment: @Mike Ok, thanks. I updated my internal neural net :)

Comment: @VitaminAqua Try to put the relevant part into a separate script and run it. Only put there the variable and `shell_exec` function, nothing else, no HTML, no other PHP. Also enable errors with `error_reporting(E_ALL)` at the beginning of your script, in case they're disabled. Just to see if the problem really is somewhere there.

Answer (score 0):

I think your forgetting to escape the closing 'P', so use:

```
 \<\/P\>
```

instead of

```
 \</P\>
```

Comment: Note: The question has been edited and it appears this answer is no longer relevant. Also a closing paragraph tag should be `</p>`, not `<\P>`

Comment: Good spot, it's easy to get the wrong way while typing on mobile, where on keyboard you wouldn't even think about it.